# Evaluate environment variable read from file in batch

Tags: batch-file, environment-variables

I read in the file `repos.txt` by the script:

```
@echo off

for /F %%s in (%~dp0repos.txt) do (
    echo %%s
)
```

The file `repos.txt` contains the lines:

```
%UserProfile%\Documents\Repository\A
%UserProfile%\Documents\Repository\B
```

The `echo` command gives me the directories without evaluating the environment variable `%UserProfile%`. This is a problem when I would like to use it with git.

How can I evaluate the environment variable?

I tried `setlocal` like done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199931/how-expand-a-cmd-shell-variable-twice-recursively) and the surrounding with [exclamation marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623704/how-to-use-an-environment-variable-as-an-environment-variable-name). Unfortunately, nothing gives the correct output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command **call** can be used to expand environment variables on assigning to an environment variable as this code demonstrates:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "usebackq eol=| delims=" %%s in ("%~dp0repos.txt") do (
    set "RepositoryPath=%%s"
    echo Not expanded: !RepositoryPath!
    call set "RepositoryPath=%%s"
    echo And expanded: !RepositoryPath!
)
endlocal
```